# Query on referenced document in array of documents

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections members and books, and the one book is referenced in members collection into an array of documents, like this:

Member document

```
{
    name:"Michael Mason",
    phone: "0754512542",
    state: true,
    penalties: 12.5,
    activeBorrows: [
      {
        id_book: 10,
        borrowDate: new Date(2021, 5, 15),
        returnDate: new Date(2021, 6, 15),
      },
      {
        id_book: 4,
        borrowDate: new Date(2021, 5, 15),
        returnDate: new Date(2021, 6, 30),
      },
    ],
  },
```

Book document

```
 {
    _id: 10,
    title: "C++ Programming Language",
    isbn: "9780321563842",
    authors: [
      {
        lastname: "Stroustrup",
        firstname: "Bjarne ",
        born: new Date(1973, 12, 26),
      },
    ],
    categories: ["software", "programare"],
    published: 2013,
    nrPages: 1368,
  },
```

I want to extract for a member details of the books he borrowed, for example member with name "Michael Mason" to print details of books with id 10 and 4, from the book collection.
This is what I tried but it prints an error at "$in" command:

```
var member = db.members.find({"name":"Michael Mason"},{"activeBorrows":1},{$unwind:"$activeBorrows"})
var book = db.books.find({"_id":{"$in":member["activeBorrows"]}})
print(book);
```

I am thinking this way or using aggregate but I don't figure out how to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use aggregations

- `$match` to get particular document
- `$lookup` to join collections

Here is the code

```
db.Member.aggregate([
  { "$match": { name: "Michael Mason" } },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Book",
      "localField": "activeBorrows.id_book",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "joinBooks"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y0hsF4daIXp)**

Note : name is not a unique, So better you should have any unique id